# Input Validation WCF

Tags: wcf

It seems that is you mark a [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) property in an object you create and use the [IsRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired.aspx) attribute, you are only  telling the comsumer that the tag for this proerty needs to be in the input schema. I need to tell the customer is not only needs to be in the input schema it needs to be populated with a value. And even further why not have a regular expression to check against?

Can someone give me a sample on how to tell the consumer of a WCF method input validation for the value being pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to input validation in WCF is to use a custom schema validator. Microsoft has a tutorial on the subject here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647820.aspx

Note: as RQDQ mentioned, this is non-trivial. However, the approach outlined in the link above is at the very least fairly modular.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such mechanism at the current time in WCF (at least that I know of).

What you're describing is very non-trivial.  For example, the same data control might be used by more than one operation.  Each operation might specify a different set of requirements for what is valid input.  Those requirements may be very complicated (e.g. some fields are required given the value of other fields on that or another DataContract).

There is no free lunch here - API documentation is the only way I know of to specify this level of information.

Comment: I want the users to pass an Order object I created to my wcf method. The Order object has some required proerties have values in them. I cant tell wcf if check the Order object to see if the user entered values for these properties? Does the [NotNullValidator] help me at all with this?